# libpcan.h not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have working code on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM that uses libpcan as a dependency. Everything runs great.

Now I am trying to build the same project on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 partition. Suddenly libpcan is not recognized as a package.

I have tried to reinstall libpcan using rosdep

```
$ roscd libpcan
$ rosdep install libpcan
$ rosmake libpcan
```

However I cannot find the install_libpcan.sh setup file to run after installing. I've since checked the directory found with

```
$ roscd libpcan
```

on both my VM and my partition, and they have the exact same contents: a cmake directory, and a package.xml.

Has anyone come across this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237290/libpcan.h-not-found/) by [jdcarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26475/jdcarp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can be solved by downloading and installing the [PeakCAN Linux drivers](http://www.peak-system.com/fileadmin/media/linux/index.htm).

---

Originally posted by [jdcarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26475/jdcarp/) with karma: 18 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0